# React errors when deployed with CI on Netlify but works fine if deployed from CLI?

Tags: netlify

Im able to deploy my site with the Netlify CLI and everything works great. When I try to set up continuous integration I don't get a build error but when I visit the site React throws an error:

```
Error: Minified React error #130 https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]=
```

Steps with CLI:

1. run 'npm run build' from project root
2. cd to 'build'
3. run 'netlify deploy'
4. when I see this message choose yes: No site id specified, create a new site (Y/n)
5. hit enter when I see this:  Path to deploy? (current dir)

If I click on the link provided the site looks good and no errors in the console.

This is my netlify.toml file:

```
[Settings]
  ID = "MyProject"

# Settings in the [build] context are global and are applied to all contexts unless otherwise overridden by more specific contexts.  

[build]
# This is the directory that you are publishing from (relative to root of your repo)
  publish = "build"
# This will be your default build command
  command = "npm run build"
```

1. Logged into Netlify I choose "new site from git" and choose my repo
   and branch
2. I leave the build command and publish directory fields empty as they will be overridden by the netlify.toml file. (Ive tried entering the same values as in the netlify.toml just to be sure)

Here are the logs:

```
9:00:14 AM: Build ready to start
9:00:16 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
9:00:17 AM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
9:00:17 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
9:00:17 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
9:00:17 AM: git clone git@github.com:myname/project
9:00:18 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
9:00:19 AM: Found netlify.toml. Overriding site configuration
9:00:19 AM: Starting build script
9:00:19 AM: Installing dependencies
9:00:20 AM: v8.9.4 is already installed.
9:00:21 AM: Now using node v8.9.4 (npm v5.6.0)
9:00:21 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.3.6, read from environment
9:00:22 AM: Using ruby version 2.3.6
9:00:22 AM: Using PHP version 5.6
9:00:22 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
9:00:22 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
9:00:22 AM: Started restoring cached yarn cache
9:00:22 AM: Finished restoring cached yarn cache
9:00:23 AM: Installing yarn at version 1.3.2
9:00:23 AM: Installing Yarn!
9:00:23 AM: > Downloading tarball...
9:00:23 AM: [1/2]: https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.3.2/yarn-v1.3.2.tar.gz --> /tmp/yarn.tar.gz.PPdZXZ4deY
9:00:23 AM:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
9:00:23 AM:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
9:00:23 AM: 
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100    91  100    91    0     0   1387      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1400
9:00:23 AM: 
  0     0    0   608    0     0
9:00:23 AM: 2313      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2313
9:00:23 AM: 
 39  865k   39  338k    0     0   440k
9:00:23 AM:     0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  440k
9:00:23 AM: 
100  865k  100  865k    0     0   880k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2451k
9:00:23 AM: [2/2]: https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/1.3.2/yarn-v1.3.2.tar.gz.asc --> /tmp/yarn.tar.gz.PPdZXZ4deY.asc
9:00:23 AM: 
100    95  100    95    0     0   6080      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6080
9:00:24 AM: 0
9:00:24 AM:      0    0   612    0     0   5100      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5100
9:00:24 AM: 
100  1027  100  1027    0
9:00:24 AM:  0   6431      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6431
9:00:24 AM: > Verifying integrity...
9:00:24 AM: gpg: Signature made Thu 02 Nov 2017 04:44:10 PM UTC using RSA key ID FD2497F5
9:00:24 AM: gpg: Good signature from "Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>"
9:00:24 AM: gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
9:00:24 AM: gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
9:00:24 AM: Primary key fingerprint: 72EC F46A 56B4 AD39 C907  BBB7 1646 B01B 86E5 0310
9:00:24 AM:      Subkey fingerprint: 6A01 0C51 6600 6599 AA17  F081 46C2 130D FD24 97F5
9:00:24 AM: > GPG signature looks good
9:00:24 AM: > Extracting to ~/.yarn...
9:00:24 AM: > Adding to $PATH...
9:00:24 AM: > We've added the following to your /opt/buildhome/.profile
9:00:24 AM: > If this isn't the profile of your current shell then please add the following to your correct profile:
9:00:24 AM: export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
9:00:24 AM: 
9:00:24 AM: > Successfully installed Yarn 1.3.2! Please open another terminal where the `yarn` command will now be available.
9:00:25 AM: Installing NPM modules using Yarn version 1.3.2
9:00:25 AM: yarn install v1.3.2
9:00:26 AM: [1/4] Resolving packages...
9:00:28 AM: [2/4] Fetching packages...
9:00:52 AM: info fsevents@1.1.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
9:00:52 AM: info "fsevents@1.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
9:00:52 AM: [3/4] Linking dependencies...
9:01:04 AM: [4/4] Building fresh packages...
9:01:07 AM: success Saved lockfile.
9:01:07 AM: Done in 41.51s.
9:01:07 AM: NPM modules installed using Yarn
9:01:08 AM: Installing missing commands
9:01:08 AM: Executing user command: npm run build
9:01:08 AM: > my-project@0.0.1 build /opt/build/repo
9:01:08 AM: > npm-run-all build-css build-js
9:01:09 AM: > my-project@0.0.1 build-css /opt/build/repo
9:01:09 AM: > node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/
9:01:09 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:09 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/Account/AccountDetails.css
9:01:09 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:09 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/App/App.css
9:01:09 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:09 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/App/AppHeader.css
9:01:09 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:09 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/App/base.css
9:01:09 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:09 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/App/btn.css
9:01:09 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:09 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/App/form.css
9:01:09 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:09 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/App/functional.css
9:01:09 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:09 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/App/functional/margin-padding.css
9:01:09 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:09 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/App/functional/section.css
9:01:09 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:09 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/BreadCrumbs/BreadCrumbs.css
9:01:09 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:09 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/Comments/Comment.css
9:01:09 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:09 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/Comments/NewComment.css
9:01:10 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:10 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/EventPage/EventPage.css
9:01:10 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:10 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/EventsPage/EventsPage.css
9:01:10 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:10 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/GroupPage/GroupPage.css
9:01:10 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:10 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/GroupPage/GroupPageEvents.css
9:01:10 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:10 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/GroupsPage/GroupsPage.css
9:01:10 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:10 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/LocationPage/LocationPage.css
9:01:10 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:10 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/LocationsPage/LocationsPage.css
9:01:10 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:10 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/Members/Members.css
9:01:10 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:10 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/ModalContent/ModalContent.css
9:01:10 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:10 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/PageNotFound/PageNotFound.css
9:01:10 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:10 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/PeoplePage/PeoplePage.css
9:01:10 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:10 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/UserPic/UserPic.css
9:01:10 AM: Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
9:01:10 AM: Wrote CSS to /opt/build/repo/src/components/vars.css
9:01:10 AM: Wrote 25 CSS files to /opt/build/repo/src/
9:01:10 AM: > my-project@0.0.1 build-js /opt/build/repo
9:01:10 AM: > react-scripts build
9:01:11 AM: Creating an optimized production build...
9:01:34 AM: Compiled successfully.
9:01:34 AM: File sizes after gzip:
9:01:34 AM:   133.85 KB  build/static/js/main.3205f98f.js
9:01:34 AM:   4.19 KB    build/static/css/main.befef5be.css
9:01:34 AM: The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
9:01:34 AM: To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json.
9:01:34 AM: For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:
9:01:34 AM:   "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",
9:01:34 AM: The build folder is ready to be deployed.
9:01:34 AM: You may serve it with a static server:
9:01:34 AM:   yarn global add serve
9:01:34 AM:   serve -s build
9:01:35 AM: Caching artifacts
9:01:35 AM: Started saving node modules
9:01:35 AM: Finished saving node modules
9:01:35 AM: Started saving yarn cache
9:01:35 AM: Finished saving yarn cache
9:01:35 AM: Started saving pip cache
9:01:35 AM: Finished saving pip cache
9:01:35 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
9:01:35 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
9:01:35 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
9:01:35 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
9:01:35 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
9:01:35 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
9:01:37 AM: Cached node version v8.9.4
9:01:39 AM: Build script success
9:01:39 AM: Starting to deploy site from 'build'
9:01:39 AM: Starting post processing
9:01:39 AM: Post processing done
9:01:40 AM: Site is live
9:01:54 AM: Finished processing build request in 1m38.175862661s
```

The site is deployed: https://pedantic-sam-d59591.netlify.com/

Netlify isnt aware of any errors but React throws this error when I view the page:

react-dom.production.min.js:187 Error: Minified React error #130; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run Netlify's tech support team.

In general these kinds of questions are easier to address via our helpdesk, reachable via support@netlify.com.  I say that not because I want to have this conversation with you again over there, but because the Support team has access to your build settings and full deploy logs and the files created by your build, and can give you answers that are about your actual deploy, rather than the generic troubleshooting tips I'm going to give you here.  We might still end up giving you somewhat "how to debug it yourself" type tips - but we can at least tailor them to your URL's and current settings. Anyhow, on to those tips...

At a high level, deploying via CLI means we don't change your files - you build them locally, send them to us, we send them to our CDN, done.  When we deploy via a git commit, we build them - in our build environment, which is almost certainly different than yours.  Some key traits of that build environment are described in these articles:

- [how we build](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/10/18/how-our-build-bots-build-sites/)
- [build settings](https://www.netlify.com/docs/build-settings/)

The first-pass debugging advice we tend to give, once we confirm there are no total bogons in your configuration like a nonexistent deployment directory (we can see that is not the case in the logs you shared here, thanks for not cutting them off too early!), is based on the versions and settings of software we use to build, specifically:

- Node 8
- Yarn 1.3.2 (do you instead use npm locally?  remove yarn.lock from your repo and we'll use it too!)
- `NODE_ENV=development`

You can override all of these as shown in that linked build settings article.  Once you've gotten versions and setting synced, if things still aren't building right, it's worth manually triggering a deploy with the dependency (build) cache cleared.  You can hit the 'trigger deploy' button on the deploy listings page to initiate a build without a commit, and when you do, you can select "clear build cache".  I can see that you aren't using a cache in your logs (lines 2-3) so this isn't what's affecting you but might help the next person who finds this question & answer.

In the end, if you have versions synced, and cache isn't the problem, the next easiest debug step is to compare the files we've built with the ones you build locally, using a tool like `diff -r`. But how do you see all of those files easily?  This tiny icon on every completed deploy logs page lets you download a copy of the deploy:

[image: picture of the deploy logs with download button highlit]

If in the end none of that helps, you can find instructions for debugging your build inside our build environment at the end of the first article I linked.